# htaccess re-write for restful api

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration

I am creating a restful based API and am stuck on htaccess re-write rules.

I am currently using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works, however I want it to exclude file extension directories and the current exclusion doesn't make a difference.

E.g.

- /api/object/1/list is valid
- /api/object/test.php/js/css etc.. is not valid

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` includes a `.` before all the included extensions.

Remove the `\.` from your condition and it should work like so.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]`

Do note that you will not be able to use the included extension names in your method/object name or method/object name ending with these extension names.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can omit (.*) then your condition would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
```